# Check for datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

Hay.. I am facing a problem, I am getting a string 'strData' which contain user search value.
I am splitting that string by space and putting in array. how can i check that the string which i getting from array is date or not? if is it date type so i will need to convert it in datetime.

I am using MySql as a database. I am doing like this

```
DATE_FORMAT(ProjectDueDate, '%m/%d/%Y') like '%3/9/2011%'
```

It is not working fine but if i take date like this  `'%03/09/2011%'`
then its working fine. How can i handle date like `'%3/9/2011%'`

I am using c# with MySql

Comment: And in which language do you wish to do this?

Comment: Could you explain the scenario as to where you are getting the date from? User input or any other external source? and how/where (in c# or mysql) do you want the date handling to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime.TryParse`

I am assuming it because you are a c#/asp.net developer per your SO profile :)
Please tag the question with language/tool so as not leave people guessing.

EDIT:

How about `DATE_FORMAT(ProjectDueDate, '%c/%e/%Y')`?
This is derived as per mysql date format documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

> %c     Month, numeric (0..12)
>   %e     Day of the month, numeric (0..31)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the C# DateTime class, you can use the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) method.  This will let you know whether the string contains a valid `DateTime` value or not.